# Oorderby after groupby LINQ C# (without lambda)

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, sql-order-by

I am currently doing a groupby on a table as below:

```
var Query2 =
from b in Books
group b.BookPubid by b.BookPubid into g
select new
{
    PublisherID = g.Key,
    TotalBooks = g.Count()

};
```

What I want to do is `orderby` PublisherId. Any suggesetions please? I tried looking at posts but couldnt really find one that uses above format instead of using => to iterate through each rows..

Ty

Comment: from b in Books
group b.BookPubid by b.BookPubid into g
orderby g.key
select new
{
    PublisherID = g.Key,
    TotalBooks = g.Count()

}; this will work.

Comment: Hey gets error at the orderby line " name 'b' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: There is no need to order after you do the group by you always should do the order before the group by.  The order by maintains the order for other fields and doing the order before is more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about what happens after you grouped by `BookPubid`. You now have an enumerable of `IGrouping<int, Book>` called `g`, assuming the publisher ID is an `int`. Notice how the publisher ID becomes the `Key` of each `IGrouping`. Therefore, you should order by `g.Key`:

```
var Query2 =
from b in list
group b.BookPubid by b.BookPubid into g
orderby g.Key
select new
{
    PublisherID = g.Key,
    TotalBooks = g.Count()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var Query2 =
from b in Books
orderby b.BookPubid
group b.BookPubid by b.BookPubid into g
select new
{
   PublisherID = g.Key,
   TotalBooks = g.Count()
};
```